# How to solve this summation: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k2^{k}}{(k+2)!}$

Tags: summation, factorial

**How do I solve this summation?**

I have tried simplifying k on the numerator with the factorial in the denominator but it just gets me nowhere.

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k2^{k}}{(k+2)!}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{k2^k}{(k+2)!}=\frac{(k+2-2)2^k}{(k+2)!}=\frac{(k+2)2^k}{(k+2)!}-\frac{2\cdot2^k}{(k+2)!}=\frac{2^k}{(k+1)!}-\frac{2^{k+1}}{(k+2)!}$$

You get a telescopic sum.

Comment: I thought that maybe you could form a telescopic sum but I couldn't figure it out! Thanks!

Comment: @Csmity The reason why I thought about this solution is that you had $k+2$ in the denominator and $k$ at the top. Their difference is exactly the $2$ in $2^k$, thus it was natural to write $k+2-k=2$ or $k=(k+2)-2$ and see what we get....

Answer (score 4):

### Using the Hint given by N.S.:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k2^{k}}{(k+1)!}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k+2-2)2^{k}}{(k+2)!}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{(k+1)!}-\frac{2^{k+1}}{(k+2)!}$$

Using telescopic sum we get:

$$\frac{2}{2!}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}=1-\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}$$